# html file not extending

Tags: django, django-templates

I extended the base file and the directory is correct and Iam still getting normal style.

```
{% extends "music/base.html" %} 
{% block body %}    
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <img src="{% static 'music/image/Robot-PNG-File.png' %}" class="rounded-circle" alt="face" style='max-height:200px'><br>
    <h2>{{album.album_title}}</h2>
    <h3>{{album.artist}}</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for songs in album.song_set.all%}
            <li>{{songs.song_title}}- {{songs.file_type}}</li>
        {% endfor %}<br>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

This is the base html.I copied this from bootstrap 4.0.I included the static files of bootstrap also.yesterday it worked fine.But today its not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Isai</title>
    {% load staticfiles %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'music/Stylesheet.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You haven't included enough information. What's the name of the template you have shown? What's the view that is using the template? What does the rendered html look like? What do you expect it to look like? What is "normal style"

Comment: show your directory structure

Comment: I jus copied bootstrap 4 link and it worked bro..Now i want to know about another one.I want to load the image in the static file under if condition.For eg:I want to load the static image file of taylor swift if we clicked taylor swift song.How to do that???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are storing the *templates* and *static* assets at the same directory:

```
{% extends "music/base.html" %} 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'music/Stylesheet.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
```

Since you mentioned the template is loading, I guess the `music` folder is your *templates folder*.

What you have to do is create a folder for your static assets (css, js, etc.).

Usually we store it at:

```
/static/css/
```

It's also a good idea to store them in different places.

After you do that, move your `Stylesheet.css` file to `/static/css/`.

And don't forget to add this folder to the `STATICFILES_DIRS` configuration in your **settings.py**.

**settings.py**

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Then you can update your css reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/Stylesheet.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
```

You can read more about [static files management on the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: I used the link.I also added the static dir in settings.py...everything is working fine now.Thank you